# Перенаправление лога работы Jenkins в файл

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Мне необходимо видеть 'сквозной' лог работы Jenkins-сервера. По умолчанию Jenkins пишет лог с момента своего старта. Как я понял, Jenkins просто логгирует информацию согласно заданным настройкам в stdout.

Мне же необходимо, чтобы эта информация записывалась в файл (в идеале - в разные, что и позволит мне видеть лог работы сервера с момента каждого запуска до окончания работы).

Каким образом можно это сделать?

P.S. Вариант запуска сервера посредством внешнего скрипта с перенаправлением вывода не очень подходит, т.к. в случае, например, перезагрузки сервера, лог будет опять писаться в stdout.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Альтернативный путь: stdout направить в стек ELK (elasticsearch + logstash + kibana). Даст вам централизованное хранение логов в БД, поиск событий по логам, выгрузку любых метрик. А ещё облегчит масштабирование, то есть если у вас вместо одного дженкинса станет 10 (а десять слейвов — вообще не редкость), то мониторить их будет не в 10 раз сложнее, а всего в пару.